# What were the additional 40 plagues?

Tags: halacha, history, commentaries

There's an argument between Rabbi Akiva and Rabbi Eliezer, how many plagues there actually were in Egypt. R. Akiva says 50 and Rabbi Eliezer says 40.
Do we actually know what were the additional plagues ?

thank you all in advance

Comment: http://allyourbeis.blogspot.com/2010/04/250-plagues-at-sea.html

Comment: There were only 10 main plagues, the argument is about SUB-plagues, in other words, if each of them can be subdivided into "stages" or "subparts".